# Drawing a lanelist's members in cartesian coordinate system in java

Tags: java, drawing

I want to draw a lanelist's members in Cartesian coordinate system. But some of the lanes (including X&Y axis) axes do not appear. Tanx for your help.

```
public class Paint extends JPanel {

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);
    this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    g.setColor(Color.orange);
    g.drawLine(0, -10000, 0, 10000);// Y coordinate definition

    g.setColor(Color.orange);
    g.drawLine(-10000, 0, 10000, 0);// // X coordinate definition

     for (int i1 = 0; i1 < Lanelist.size(); i1++) {// drawing lanes in the lanelist
        int x1;
        int y1;
        int x2;
        int y2;

        x1 = (int) Math.round(Lanelist.get(i1).origNode.x);
        y1 = (int) Math.round(Lanelist.get(i1).origNode.y);
        x2 = (int) Math.round(.Lanelist.get(i1).destNode.x);
        y2 = (int) Math.round(Lanelist.get(i1).origNode.y);

        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }
 }
}
```

**main class**
    public class Logistics{

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IloException {

 JFrame f2=new JFrame("Title");;
 f2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 Paint pl=new Paint();
 f2.setSize(99999, 99999);
 f2.setVisible(true);

 f2.add(pl);
}
}
```

Comment: Based on your example, nothing will paint, in fact, it won't compile. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses.  Don't forget to include data which can be used to replicate the issue

Comment: Thank you for your help. Actually it does but not every part of it (paints just one or two of the lanes). My logistics class(main) is much more bigger than I put here. I did not put other parts of my code here because I think my problem's source cannot be related to them.